# Java Spring Boot Circular Dependency on one environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have a spring boot application which runs well on my local, UAT, and Prod environments but when I deploy it in a staging environment, it gives the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Bean 1': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Class 1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Bean2 of type Class1': Bean with the name 'Bean2' has been injected into other beans [Bean 3] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

I am not sure if it's related to the build process or what. I have checked the code, there are no circular dependencies. When I annotate Bean2 with `@Lazy` on Class3, it works well. But I am not able to figure out why it works on other environments and this annotation is needed only for the Staging.

Comment: In spring there no specific bean creation order is maintained. you can used @DependsOn to maintain the order if you have dependent beans.

Comment: Like I said, @lazy can also solve the issue. But my point is why only one environment and why always. If there is no specific order, it should be a success at least once.

Comment: Nevermind, there was a circular dependency and spring boot tries to break dependency which depends on OS, JVM, filesystems, etc factors.